# Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following code - All it does it grabs the value in a text box, performs regex on the string and then counts how many asterisks are in the string value:

```
var textBoxValue = $(textbox).val();

function countHowManyWildCards(stringToSearch) {

    var regex = new RegExp(/\*/g);
    var count = stringToSearch.toString().match(regex).length;
    return count;

}

if (countHowManyWildCards(textBoxValue) > 1) {

//Other code
}
```

The code seems to work, but there is an error appearing on:

```
stringToSearch.toString().match(regex).length;
```

The error states:

> Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

But I am unclear why the code works, but I still have this error? Can someone fill me in on why this happening?

Comment: [.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) says it return __An Array containing the matched results or null if there were no matches.__ So you should check if its `null` before access length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `match` is failing and not returning any array as a result calling `.length` on it will throw that error.

To fix this you can use:

```
var count = (stringToSearch.match(regex) || []).length;
```

to take care of the case when `match` fails. `|| []` will return an empty array when match fails and `[].length` will get you `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [.match(regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is `null` if there are no matches.

Answer (score 1):

stringToSearch.toString().match(regex) will return null if stringToSearch does not contain any '*'